# Redirecting http to https for login controller only in CakePHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, redirect

I've been trying to redirect http access to https in my CakePHP project. 
It is easy to do so by modifying app/webroot/.htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # added for redirecting http to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, if I try to redirect only login controller to https, I cannot do it.  For example,

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/login/.*$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The RewriteCond above doesn't work, because still all connections are redirected to https.  I've been modifying the regular expression in the RewriteCond for last few hours with no success.

I searched the web and Stack Overflow for similar problems, but I couldn't find for CakePHP.  Does anyone have some idea?

I use CakePHP2.7.5, Apache2.2.27, CentOS6.7.  Cake is installed in DocumentRoot.  No special settings.  I restart Apache every time I modify .htaccess.

Comment: Why do you only want to redirect login controller? Why not just force https throughout?

Comment: CakePHP has a great **Security Component** with an option to [force a secured connection](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#restrict-actions-to-ssl) for defined actions...

Comment: It most likely doesn't work because you cached the rules with 301. Clear your browser cache or try in a new window and see if your modified rule for login controller works then.

Comment: I can't force https throughout because most pages contain ads that do not support https conbection.

Comment: Security Component did not work for my case because when it redirects, it loses posted information.  It seems that redirection must be done outside of PHP somehow.

Comment: I also suspected browser cache, but it was not it because if I made some other change, it worked.  Only this part doesn't work.